# Install TagLib API with .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net

I wanted to install Taglib via NuGet in Visual Studio 2013. Is there any way?

I get the following error message:

> Install failed. Rolling back...
>   Install-Package : Could not install package 'taglibcpp 1.9.1-beta8'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.

Comment: See http://taglib.github.io/#language-bindings